# Voltage Gain Expression

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function, gain

I had a homework problem where I was supposed to find an expression for H(ω) = V<sub>o</sub>/V<sub>s</sub> of the op-amp shown below:

[image]

However, when I found my own expression, it turned out to be a very messy fraction that may be difficult to solve.

Is there a simpler form or method of finding the expression? My work for the problem is shown below.

[image]

Comment: You can simplify the expression further (didn't check its correctness though).

Comment: In fact it doesn't look correct based on units analysis. The gain is supposed to be unit-less, but the second term in your expression seem to yield units of resistance.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yea I'm not entirely sure where I went wrong with the fraction. I've been at the problem for a while

Comment: use \$Z_1\$ and \$Z_2\$ for the algebra, then plug in for \$Z_1 , Z_2\$ in the end. easier that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend taking a look at your first equation. It is a voltage divider, but this wont work for two reasons:

First, this divider implies Vo is at the other node of the R1-C1 branch, and implies the output of the op-amp is grounded.
Second, the negative terminal of the op amp is actually at ground potential.

You might remember from electronics that there is a “virtual short” between the two input nodes of an ideal op-amp, meaning they have equal voltage. The positive node of the op-amp input is at ground, so this means the negative input node is at ground. Also, there is a “virtual open-circuit” at the op-amp inputs, so current cannot flow into the op-amp. From this you can generate some different equations, which should hopefully get you squared away. I’ve attached some work to get you started.  [image]

Answer (score 1):

If you had one resistor \$R_f\$ in the feedback path and one resistor in the input \$R_1\$ then the gain would be \$-R_f/R_1\$ (inverting config). The situation has slightly changed. Now there is an impedance \$Z_f\$ in the feedback path and an impedance \$Z_1\$ in the input section. What should the gain be? Naturally, \$-Z_f/Z_1\$. Can you calculate these separately and substitute in the formula and simplify?

[image]

**Units check:** \$RC\$ has units of time, \$s\$ has units of frequency. so every term checks out and the gain is unitless.

Comment: Yes - most simple derivation of the transfer function. It is a typical bandpass function .

Answer (score 1):

Well, using the standard [inverting amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Inverting_amplifier) formula and an ideal opamp, we can see that:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{v}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\text{R}_2\text{||}\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}}{\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}}=\frac{\text{R}_2\cdot\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}}{\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}}=$$
$$\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{s}+1}\cdot\frac{\text{sC}_1}{\text{C}_1\text{R}_1\text{s}+1}=\frac{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2\text{s}}{\left(\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{s}+1\right)\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_1\text{s}+1\right)}\tag1$$

Now, when working with sinusoidal signals we can use \$\text{s}:=\text{j}\omega\$ (where \$\text{j}^2=-1\$ and \$\omega=2\pi\text{f}\$ with \$\text{f}\$ is the frequency of the input signal in Hertz). So, we get:

$$\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=\frac{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2\text{j}\omega}{\left(\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{j}\omega+1\right)\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_1\text{j}\omega+1\right)}=\frac{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2\omega\text{j}}{\left(1+\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\omega\text{j}\right)\left(1+\text{C}_1\text{R}_1\omega\text{j}\right)}\tag2$$

So, the absolute value if given by:

$$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2\omega}{\sqrt{1+\left(\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\omega\right)^2}\cdot\sqrt{1+\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_1\omega\right)^2}}\tag3$$

And the argument is given by:

$$\arg\left(\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\left(\arctan\left(\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\omega\right)+\arctan\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_1\omega\right)\right)\tag4$$

Answer (score 1):

All expression seen so far may even be correct, but they are all not friendly, they do not talk to us, they do not make clear the circuit behaviour and how it is changed by the components value.

Vatché Vorperian is a master in the art of writing what he calls meaningful expressions. Visiting his channel https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLe2E5ZXljENhSs5aj9OTLTAfqufA_P4wL may indeed be worthwhile.

Yet another one often surfs this site more or less anonymously giving away masterpieces.

Back to the topic a transfer function is best written as an "in band" gain (if there's one) and a fraction accounting for factorised poles and zeros.

So whether you start from the good old circuit analysis laws and hardly climb the mountain of algebra or instead you master the art of fast circuit analysis you should aim to something of this kind

$$ G=-\frac{R_2}{R_1}\frac{\frac{s}{\omega_1}}{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_1}+1\right)\left(\frac{s}{\omega_2}+1\right)} 
\quad\text{;}\quad\omega_1=\frac{1}{R_1C_1}\quad\text{;}\quad\omega_2=\frac{1}{R_2C_2}
$$